# NSPredicate predicateWithFormat for NSMetaDataQuery in iOS

Tags: ios, nspredicate, nsmetadataquery

I need to append my custom string into `NSPredicate`.

So I wrote following codes.

```
self.query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
[self.query setSearchScopes: [NSArray arrayWithObject:NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]];

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like '%@*'",NSMetadataItemFSNameKey,whereAreYou];

NSLog(@"%@",pred.description);

[self.query setPredicate:pred];
```

However when I test it , it only return following value.

```
kMDItemFSName LIKE "%@*"
```

the placeholder `%@` is not append correctly. It only showing `%@` sign.

How can I do that?

Comment: what type of whereAreYou?

Comment: yes that is String and i am sure it has value.

Comment: I suggest you try NSString stringWithFormat first. And also look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/predicates/Articles/pCreating.html

Comment: No bro . i have already tried like you said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Format arguments inside quotation marks are not expanded by `predicateWithFormat`,
therefore `@"%K like '%@*'"` does not work.

This should work:

```
NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@*", whereAreYou];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE %@", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey, pattern];
```